# How to update git directory to deployed code in Openshift

Tags: git, ssh, openshift

I have started using Openshift to deploy a Django app and am still rather ignorant about a lot of things.
I now realise I have been doing something silly in that I have been working directly on the deployed code through the SSH shell (in app-root > repo). How can I correct my git branch head so that, when I clone the repo or update my working directory using git, I can get the latest deployed version of the code?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should use an SFTP/SCP program to download all of your code to your local workstation, then use git to clone your application's git repository locally, and copy your code into that git repo.  Then do a git add, git commit, git push to push the code back to OpenShift